# Earliest systemd target for running Python script

Tags: systemd-startup

I have an LED strip connected to my Raspberry Pi Zero W, and I would like to run a Python script to turn on the LED’s as soon as possible after boot.

In my systemd unit file, I’m using `After=multi-user.target`, but I’m wondering if there is an earlier target that I can be using.

Comment: This Question is not Pi specific, and is unanswerable. It depends on what the script does. "Earlier" is a meaningless concept in `systemd`.

Comment: I normally set things up with `After=network.target` and `WantedBy=multi-user.target` and let systemd work out when to start my service.

Answer (score 4):

I would say the earliest usable target is the `sysinit.target`. But because there is nothing known about the needed resources of the LED strip it may fail. You can try other targets. The next could be the `basic.target` or some others between them, e.g. `the sockets.target`. Have a look at [systemd bootup — System bootup process](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/bootup.html) what targets can be used and try what's the earliest one for your project.